# C Char multidimensional Array Definition

Tags: c, arrays

C is like chinese to me but i got to work with some code

```
struct Message {
    unsigned char      state;
};

char state   [4][4] = { "OFF", "ON", "IL1", "IL2" };
```

This is a simple server that receives a message. The Struct part of it is obvious, but then theres that char array thing. Does this say theres 4 different char arrays, each containing 4 chars? What exactly is going on here? I know this sounds stupid but I cant figure it out.

Comment: Yes, that is, in this case 3 char + null char

Comment: `C is like chinese to me` isn't this a top phrase for IT college drop-outs?

Comment: I dont know, my friends all graduated :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that `state` is an array of 4 char arrays, each of them is an array of 4 char, and they are initialized with the values "OFF\0", "ON\0", "IL1\0" and "IL2\0"

```
         +----+----+----+----+
state => |OFF |ON  |IL1 |IL2 |
         +----+----+----+----+
         ^state[0]
              ^state[1]
                   ^state[2]
                        ^state[4]
```

Comment: So the 
{ "OFF", "ON", "IL1", "IL2" }
part just "labels" the "rows" of the array?

Comment: They are the content of the array.

Comment: So, since they are all 3- char- content, 
char state [4][3] would have been sufficient, right?

Comment: no. Note that I added `\0` at the end of each word, as in C string there is another hidden character, `\0`, called the null terminator that signals the end of the string, and you need to have space for it too. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Comment: You welcome. It's a little bit confusing at the beginning but it gets easier :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a two-dimensional array. It creates an array of 4 elements, each of which is an array of 4 char.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this say theres 4 different char arrays, each containing 4 chars?

That's exactly right: `state` is an array of four `char` sub-arrays.

Each sub-array is four `chars` long. The corresponding string literal (`"OFF"` etc) is padded with NULs to four characters, and copied into the sub-array.

Answer (score 0):

char state[4][4] declared at the end is a 2 dimensional array having 4 rows with 4 columns in each row. The values you have assigned will be stored into positions state[0][0], state[0][1], state[0][2], state[0][3].

Answer (score 0):

In C, you deal with strings as `char*`, or arrays of `char`. Therefore, when you have an array of strings, you have an array of an array of chars.